# How to test if a writelock is locked with trylock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

What I need to do: a method acquires a read or a write lock, another method sets it free. So I've been reading and found ReentrantReadWriteLock, which has two nested classes, ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock, which as far as I understand, can be obtained like this:

```
 private final ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new  ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private final Lock read = readWriteLock.readLock();
private final Lock write = readWriteLock.writeLock();
```

As an example. So my understanding is that readlock() and writelock() are two constructor that give a Lock object. And I could test if the lock is being used or not with tryLock

It's just that I don't really understand how to just know if there's a lock in place, and instead writeLock.trylock() seems to acquire it, if possible.
And  so I can do something like:

```
if (read.tryLock()) {
    read.unlock();
} else {
    return false;
}
```

And it would try to aquire the lock and "and returns immediately with the value true". But it still holds the read lock, so I said, fine, I unlock it.

But that's not really what I want, because I just want to free the lock that was (IF it was) set previously by another method. I don't want this method to lock anything, I want it to test the lock, if it's in place, unlock.

Different ways of doing this (but that I do not know if are valid): holdsLock and isHeldByCurrentThread, that are used for Object and ReentrantLocks, and I don't really know but I guess another way of solving this problem would be to create two reentrantLocks, use one as a write lock and another a read lock, and use isHeldByCurrentThread to merely check what I described above (but again, I just believe this, I don't really know).

Sorry if it's confusing, please ask me to clarify anything that is needed, tried my best explaining the issue.

Comment: You can't unlock a lock owned by another thread, only that thread can. If your current thread owns the lock, then unlock it. If you don't know if your current thread owns the lock, then you have a design issue.

Comment: I get what you're saying @SotiriosDelimanolis but it's before unlocking, I have to know if I had the lock. If that's the case I return true and if it's not I return false. And its a rmi environment, so the methods are invoked remotely. And yeah it could be a design issue but right now I do not see anything else. I'm going to re read the docummentation just in case

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html#isWriteLockedByCurrentThread--) might be helpful.

Comment: Wow I've read that doc way too many times to not see that, my bad. Now that I'm here @SotiriosDelimanolis , would it make sense to, when acquiring the lock, set a variable of some sort to a value, and just before unlocking, checking the variable? I haven't implemented it because it seemed too primitive but even with RMI I believe it could work. And thanks for the help!

Comment: also, I understand there is no isReadLockedByCurrentThread because it's not needed, right? Because of how tryLock works differently for each of them, could it be, @SotiriosDelimanolis ?